# how to redirect $routeProvider.otherwise() keeping the given query parameters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Let say I go to `/unknown-route?a=hello&b=world` and `$routeProvider` doesnt recognize it and redirect to the otherwise route:

```
otherwise({
  redirectTo: '/default-route'
});
```

Is it possible to pass the given parameters to the redirected route.

Here it would be `/default-route?a=hello&b=world`

Comment: Why are you using query parameters rather than the built in [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) of angular

Comment: Because its another app that could redirect to unknown route of this angular app

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a working solution:

```
otherwise({
  redirectTo: function() {
    return '/default-route' + location.search;
  }
})
```